# JPQL query for time difference

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpql

I have two dates in the entity REPORTED_TIME and CREATION_TIME

How can I create JPQL to fetch recored where the time difference between(CREATION_TIME-REPORTED_TIME) is only 12 hr.

I don't want any native query syntax tas we are using both Oracle and Postgres.

Can someone give a query for the same in Oracle?

### Entity

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR")
public class IncidentHdr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="INCIDENT_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="INCIDENT_ID")
    private long incidentId;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="CREATED_TIME")
    private Date createdTime;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="REPORTED_TIME")
    private Date reportedTime;



    public IncidentHdr() {
    }

    //Setter getter


}
```

Comment: Post your entity.

Comment: @jklee Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

The JPA spec doesn't contains a method for difference between date/time. But you can call functions, a little bit better than native queries. You must ensure that the [datediff function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) is available.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<IncidentHdr> query = cb.createQuery(IncidentHdr.class);
Root<IncidentHdr> root = query.from(IncidentHdr.class);

Predicate max12Hour = cb
        .lessThanOrEqualTo(
                cb.function("datediff", Long.class, cb.literal("HOUR"), root.get(IncidentHdr_.createdTime),
                        root.get(IncidentHdr_.reportedTime)),
                12L);

query.select(root)
        .where(max12Hour);

return entityManager.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

I hope it will help you.